# Struggling with VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a small spreadsheet that is intended to display current freight costs per shipping merchant, by shipping port and by office location.

I also have a smaller summary table that displays per shipping port, the cheapest rate, the merchant offering it, and the location to which it applies.

The main table is administered by our end-users, but the smaller table should update itself based on the end-user's inputs.

[image: Merchant rates]

The values in the red box are how it should look. I have managed to display the lowest rate in its row by using AGGREGATE.

But I cannot work out how to insert the corresponding depot and merchant into the summary in the same way.
I've tried various combinations of INDEX, MATCH, VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP without success - it usually ends up with a circular reference somewhere.

L

Comment: What if two locations on the same row match for the lowest rate?

Comment: This could indeed be an issue, but extremely unlikely in the real world. However, it is something that I would need to consider - I wanted to ensure the above functioned correctly before tackling possible duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try using functions like `INDEX()` instead of using **volatile functions**.

### A friendly suggestion

> `OFFSET()` is a flexible function and it can point to a
> different-sized range that is calculated on-the-fly. It is a
> **volatile function**. If you go to a completely unrelated cell and enter a number, all of the `OFFSET()` functions will calculate—even if
> that cell has nothing to do with.
>
> It has been found, **Excel** is very careful to spend time calculating
> the cells that needs to be calculated. But once you use the
> `OFFSET()`, all of the `OFFSET()` cells, plus everything downline from
> the `OFFSET()`, starts calculating after every change in the
> worksheet.
>
> Why it matters ? `INDEX()` is **not volatile**. You enjoy all of the
> **flexible goodness** of `OFFSET()` without the **time-sucking recalculations over and over**.

---

Here is shown below, what you can ***try***:

[image]

---

Getting the **MIN** values.

• Formula used in cell `AB7`

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(Q7:Z7)/ISNUMBER(Q7:Z7),1)
```

**Note:** I have used `15` which refers to `SMALL` instead of `5` with an `ISNUMBER()` Function which ignores all the text values as well as `#N/A()` as well. Thus, giving the Minimum values of each office location.

[image]

---

Getting the **Merchant** Name,

• Formula used in cell `AC7`

```
=INDEX(Q7:Z7,,MATCH(AB7,Q7:Z7,0)+1)
```

**Note:** The `MATCH()` returns the relative position of the **MIN** value column wise, and to get the **Merchant** we are simply adding 1 to it, and wrapping the whole within `INDEX()`.

---

Getting the **Depot** Name

• Formula used in cell `AD7`

```
=INDEX($Q$5:$Z$5,,MATCH(AB7,Q7:Z7,0))
```

Note: Same as above the `MATCH()` returns the min value position, and then we are wrapping it within `INDEX()` to get **DEPOT** for the respective **MIN**
values.

Also, here for the **Depot** cells I have not used **Merge & Center** instead have used the **Alignment** as **Center Across Selection**, that way it much easier to use a formula and not resorting to complicated ones. Avoid using **Merge & Center** .

[image]

**Note:** All the above formulas used, you need to fill down, and it has been assumed you may not have duplicate Min values. If you get duplicate values for **Rates** then the formulas for **Merchant** & **Depot** will change.

Comment: This is great; seems to work exactly as intended. I'll have to investigate further when dealing with possible duplicate Rates values; in the real world it is highly unlikely but entirely possible theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDEX/MATCH` wrapped with `OFFSET` to help you achieve this. This is assuming that merchants are never numeric.

Cell M3 (min) formula:

```
=MIN(B3:J3)
```

Cell N3 (merchant) formula, which locates the min(rate) in that row and returns the value 1 column to the right of it:

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(B3:K3,MATCH(MIN(B3:K3),B3:K3,0)),,1)
```

Cell O3 (depot) formula, which locates the min(rate) in that row and returns the first row in that column. Or more precisely, x-nbr of rows above it.

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(B3:K3,MATCH(MIN(B3:K3),B3:K3,0)),-ROW(A2),)
```

[image]